# Wrong array input

Tags: java, arrays, string, input

So I wanted to take the user input into a variable and then add it to the array but instead the character goes straight into the array and skips like 3 lines of code.
The Code here

```
import java.util.*;
public class Hangman{

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your word and press enter: ");
    String word = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter a relevant category and press enter: ");
    String category = sc.nextLine();
    word.toUpperCase();
    char charArray[] = new char[word.length()];


    for(int i = 0; i<=word.length(); i++){
        System.out.println("Category: " + category);
        System.out.println("Letters Guessed: " + Arrays.toString(charArray));
        System.out.println("Your guess: ");
        char guess = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
        compare(guess, word);
        charArray[i] = guess;


    }
}
public static boolean compare(char guess, String word){
    for(int i = 0; i<word.length(); i++){
        if(guess == word.charAt(i)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Output :

```
Please enter your word and press enter: 
hello
Please enter a relevant category and press enter: 
test
Category: test
Letters Guessed: [hi
Category: test
Letters Guessed: [h, l
Category: test
Letters Guessed: [h, l, m
Category: test
Letters Guessed: [h, l, m, o
Category: test
Letters Guessed: [h, l, m, o, n
Category: test
Letters Guessed: [h, l, m, o, n]
Your guess:
```

can someone give some tips

Comment: Note: `word.toUpperCase();` - Strings are immutable objects, you should assign the result back to a String. Also your `compare` method makes no sense, it always returns `true`.

Comment: Please add some more information about what this is supposed to do, exactly. You have several problems in your code but it's hard to tell which is a genuine error and which is something that you have left out to implement later. Is this supposed to be something like hangman? What's the category thing?

Answer (score 0):

Your compare method is not valid:

```
public static boolean compare(char guess, String word){
    for(int i = 0; i<word.length(); i++){
        if(guess != word.charAt(i)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should modify your `compare()` method as others have suggested, so that it does not always return true.

Second, you should use the return value in your `main()` method. It is unclear what you want to do if the comparison is true vs. false, so in general,

```
if (compare(guess, word)) { 
    /* Do something */ 
} else { 
   /* Do something else here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ambiguities in the post about expected output and actual output; following points which must be considered.

1. Strings are immutable but you are using word.toUpperCase()without assigning it. like:

   word = word.toUpperCase();
2. You are using compare method but not utilizing its decision like

   if(compare(guess, word)){

   ```
      //do something
   ```

   }